# Since updated angular 2 version, requests are getting cancelled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, webpack

So since I updated angular 2 and more few packages by `npm`,
some of my requests are just getting cancelled if I send multiple request at the same time, for example if have loop of some groups,
and I wanna get the id of each group and send it to the server in order to get something by the group id, some if this request just getting cancelled for no reason.
and if I just remove the for and just put by myself some group id and send it to the server, everything works fine.
there is nothing on the internet about this problem and this is very sucks.
this is my relevant information:

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "xxx messanger web app",
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist && npm cache clean",
        "clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
        "clean-start": "npm run clean-install && npm start",
        "watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
        "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
        "server": "webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --inline --port 8080",
        "dev": "webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --inline --port 8080",
        "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
        "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
        "lint": "tslint --force \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "start": "npm run server",
        "start:hmr": "npm run server -- --hot",
        "postinstall": "npm run webdriver-update"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://xxx.visualstudio.com/xxx/_git/xxx"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "author": "xxx xxx",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.4.9",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
        "@angular/core": "2.4.9",
        "@angular/forms": "2.4.9",
        "@angular/http": "2.4.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.9",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
        "@angular/router": "3.4.9",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.9",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.19",
        "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
        "angular-calendar": "^0.7.0",
        "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
        "angular2-tree-component": "3.1.0",
        "angular2-google-map-auto-complete": "^2.0.5",
        "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
        "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "firebase": "^3.6.5",
        "font-awesome": "^4.6.1",
        "googlemaps": "^1.12.0",
        "jquery": "^2.2.4",
        "lodash": "^4.16.4",
        "moment": "2.0.0",
        "typings": "2.1.0",
        "ng2-auto-complete": "^0.10.5",
        "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
        "ng2-dnd": "^2.1.1",
        "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
        "ng2-webstorage": "^1.3.3",
        "rdash-ui": "^1.0.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.1",
        "systemjs": "0.19.27",
        "ts-xlsx": "0.0.8",
        "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
        "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
        "@types/core-js": "^0.9.0",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.29",
        "@types/jquery": "^2.0.33",
        "@types/node": "^7.0.8",
        "@types/selenium-webdriver": "3.0.0",
        "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
        "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
        "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
        "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
        "null-loader": "0.1.1",
        "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
        "postcss-loader": "^1.1.0",
        "protractor": "^4.0.10",
        "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
        "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
        "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
        "sass-loader": " ^6.0.3",
        "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
        "ts-loader": "^2.0.1",
        "tslint": "^3.4.0",
        "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
        "typescript": "^2.0.0",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
        "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
        "webpack-dashboard": "^0.3.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": " 2.4.2"
    }
}
```

**the code with the requests:**

```
this.loggedInUser.groups.forEach((group, key) => {
    this._RoutesService.getRoutesByGroupId(group.id).map((routes, key) => {
        console.log(routes);
        if (routes && routes.length > 0) {
            let n = 0;
            routes.forEach((router, key) => {
                if (router.stations) {
                    let rout = new route(router.name, router.id, group.id);
                    router.stations.forEach((state) => {
                        let statione = new station(state.id, state.latitude, state.longitude);
                        statione.users = state.users;
                        rout.Stations.push(statione);
                    });
                    this.RoutesList.push(rout);
                }
            });
        }
        i++;
        if (i == this.loggedInUser.groups.length) {
            this.setOriginDest();
        }
    }).subscribe();
});
```

[image: The cancelled requests]

thanks..

Comment: what is the error message returned for your request?

Comment: @Aravind i edited the post

Comment: what is the actual requirement. and why do you have these many network calls, it is not at all a good practise

Comment: @Aravind I know that, this is temporary solution but i search answer for this situation.